# how to change a date format in R

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I need help in R program to  change date format from "May 29, 2015"    to    "05,29,2015".I tried this "housing$SaleDate<- as.Date(housing$SaleDate,"%Y%M%D")" but did not work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After converting to `Date` class, we may need format i.e.

```
library(lubridate)
str1 <- "May 29, 2015" 
format(mdy(str1), '%m,%d,%Y')
[1] "05,29,2015"
```

---

For the OP's `as.Date`, it would be

```
housing$SaleDate <- format(as.Date(housing$SaleDate, "%b %d, %Y"), "%m,%d,%Y")
```